# How to create new Date instance only by a day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails project I want to get a `Date` instance only by a day. Year and month are used current value.

I could write like these:

```
day = 3
date = Date.new(Date.current.year, Date.current.month, day)
```

and

```
date = Date.current.beginning_of_month + (day - 1).days
```

How would you write function like this?
Is there a better implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a Date object, you can do:

```
date.change(day: 3)
```

where date is a Date or DateTime object. Also you can do:

```
Date.today.change(day: 3)
```